# Applying a function to a Dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
def predict_age(cols):
Age = cols[0]
Pclass = cols[1]
title = cols[2]

if pd.isnull(Age):
    if title == "Dr":
        if Pclass == 1:
            return 44
        else:
            return 39
    elif title == "Master":
        if Pclass ==1:
            return 5
        elif Pclass == 2:
            return 2
        else:
            return 5
    elif title == "Miss":
        if Pclass ==1:
            return 30
        elif Pclass == 2:
            return 22
        else:
            return 16
    elif title == "Mr":
        if Pclass ==1:
            return 42
        elif Pclass == 2:
            return 34
        else:
            return 29
    elif title == "Mrs":
        if Pclass ==1:
            return 41
        elif Pclass == 2:
            return 34
        else:
            return 34
else:
    return Age

train_data['Age'] = train_data[['Age','Pclass','title']].apply(predict_age,axis=1)
train_data
```

I'm trying to apply this code to the titanic dataframe to predict the age where null values are present. However no effect occurs. If I change the axis to 0 all the values under get changed to 'null'. Can someone please help me with this.

Answer (score 1):

I ran the following code and it works fine:

```py
import pandas as pd

train_data = pd.DataFrame({
    "Age": [None, None, None],
    "Pclass": [1, 2, 1],
    "title": ["Master", "Miss", "Mr"]
})


def predict_age(cols):
    Age = cols[0]
    Pclass = cols[1]
    title = cols[2]

    if pd.isnull(Age):
        # print("passed")
        if title == "Dr":
            if Pclass == 1:
                return 44
            else:
                return 39
        elif title == "Master":
            if Pclass ==1:
                return 5
            elif Pclass == 2:
                return 2
            else:
                return 5
        elif title == "Miss":
            if Pclass ==1:
                return 30
            elif Pclass == 2:
                return 22
            else:
                return 16
        elif title == "Mr":
            if Pclass ==1:
                return 42
            elif Pclass == 2:
                return 34
            else:
                return 29
        elif title == "Mrs":
            if Pclass ==1:
                return 41
            elif Pclass == 2:
                return 34
            else:
                return 34
    else:
        return Age

train_data['Age'] = train_data[['Age','Pclass','title']].apply(predict_age, axis=1)
print(train_data)
```

Output:

```sh
   Age  Pclass   title
0    5       1  Master
1   22       2    Miss
2   42       1      Mr
```

I think for your case, it might not be evaluating the condition `if pd.isnull(Age)` as `True` for any of the cases. Try the same after putting a temp print statement after this condition as shown in the comment block of the code.

Comment: Yes, isnull() is not working for some reason. I can' figure out why that is happening. Any way I can fix it?

Comment: Check the type of the corresponding value in the `Age` column. `type(train_data.at[row_index, 'Age'])` Refer any of the row_index for which you want to change the value of `Age` field

Comment: It's float. I tried to change the return values to float, that didn't work either. Also the isnull() statement worked. It is printing a statement in the first if but when i go inside the nested if, the one dealing with the titles it doesn't execute the temp print statements.

Comment: Check the title values available in your dataframe using `print(train_data.title.unique())`. Also, changing from int to float is not required. There should be a corresponding `Dr` value for the Age field where its value is `null`

Comment: def impute_age(cols):
    Age = cols[0]
    Pclass = cols[1]
    
    if pd.isnull(Age):

        if Pclass == 1:
                return 35

        elif Pclass == 2:
            return 29

        else:
            return 24

    else:
        return Age
train_data['Age'] = train_data[['Age','Pclass']].apply(impute_age,axis=1)
train_data

Comment: This code works. it's the same just without the nested ifs. Any idea why this is happening.

Comment: It is because none of the null Age records match the title value that you have provided. That is why it did not enter the condition and ultimately skipped the `Pclass` check as welll.

Comment: There is definitely a doctor with a missing age. It doesnt seem to be accepting title.train_data[train_data['title']== 'Mr'].Even this it gives me a blank output. I had added title as an extra column. It wasn't a part of the original data frame.

Comment: If `print(train_data.title.str.contains(".*Mr.*", regex=True).sum())` gives you an output which is greater than 1 that means exact `Mr` match does not exist in your column. There can possibly be some starting or trailing spaces in `Mr`. Example, "  Mr", "Mr   " or even "   Mr   "